# Need help with notation - Supremum

Tags: real-analysis, notation, pronunciation

I'm reading a paper, '[Invariant Scattering Convolution Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.1513.pdf)'. Equation 2, page 2 reads as follows;

[image: Snippet from page 2 of the linked article]

I'm not familiar with the $\underset{u}{sup}$ notation - does this refer to the [support of the function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) $|\nabla{ \tau (u) }|$? How would I read that part of the equation out loud?

Comment: Have you tried googling "sup notation math" or similar? "Sup pronunciation math" gives the "Handbook for Spoken Mathematics" for your other question.

Comment: Thanks Mark - I did try googling for this one, and even tried Detexify, in-case it was some stand alone LaTeX symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Sup" stands for "[supremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum)", not "support" ("support" would usually be abbreviated "supp" instead).  So $$\sup_u |\nabla\tau(u)|$$ means the supremum of all values of $|\nabla\tau(u)|$; that is, the smallest number $s$ such that $|\nabla\tau(u)|\leq s$ for all $u$.

The symbol "$\sup\limits_u$" can be read aloud as "(the) sup (over $u$) of" or "the supremum (over $u$) of", where the parts in parentheses are optional and "sup" is pronounced like "soup".

Comment: You really pronounce it "soup"? I've always pronounced it "sup". And, you beat me to the chase by 10 seconds.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you!